# In Drupal 7, is there a way to pop form errors off the display stack and/or prevent their display?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 form which I'm allowing the user to submit via AJAX. If the user does not fill out required fields, or enters invalid information, I can return that and alert the user via the `form_get_errors()` function. The problem is that these values are still on the "display stack" (not the correct term, I'm sure) - when the user refreshes the page, or navigates to another one, these previous errors are displayed.

Is there a way to set these errors not to display once I've grabbed them with `form_get_errors()`?

EDIT: One option I have would be to remove all validation functions, then manually do validation in my ajax submit handler...but I feel like that defeats the purpose of this form API. I'd like to use everything built in, but I just want the error messages not to be displayed.

Comment: What kind of validation it is? You can't trust in client-side validation, since can be hacked by the user. So it's always nice idea to keep both

Comment: The validation would still be server side either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) function (which is called by `form_get_errors()`) shows it's using the Drupal 7 static cache pattern to hold the error messages. You should be able to clear that cache by calling the following in your AJAX validation function:

```
drupal_static_reset('form_set_error');
```

If you're using the AJAX provided by the form API (i.e. setting `#ajax` on your form element) you might want to look at [`#limit_validation_errors()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors) to see if that can help you out as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working - the error messages still display. Setting #limit_validation_errors doesn't seem like it would be a good idea - although it would prevent error messages from displaying, it would also prevent the elements from being validated.

Comment: Just to add more - drupal_static_reset will alter the static variable, but the 'messages' array in the $_SESSION superglobal will still be set, which is where the display is driven from, I believe. I could manually hack the values out of the session var, but I'm not sure that's the best way to handle this.

Comment: I'd just hack the values out to be honest, if you were using the FAPI fully then you wouldn't need to do any of this as validation messages display in the replacement wrapper and are immediately cleared from the session so the problem would never happen.